# I can't get angles from a binary image with squares

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, contour

I want to get the angles from the binary image in python, but I don't know how to convert this cpp to python.

If there is a other way to detect angles from this 'inspected image' for example with blob detection please let me know.

example image:

[inspected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJG65.png)

example cpp code:

```
cv::Mat input = cv::imread("../inputData/rectangles.png");

cv::Mat gray;
cv::cvtColor(input,gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);

// since your image has compression artifacts, we have to threshold the image
int threshold = 200;
cv::Mat mask = gray > threshold;

cv::imshow("mask", mask);

// extract contours
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::findContours(mask, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

for(int i=0; i<contours.size(); ++i)
{
    // fit bounding rectangle around contour
    cv::RotatedRect rotatedRect = cv::minAreaRect(contours[i]);

    // read points and angle
    cv::Point2f rect_points[4]; 
    rotatedRect.points( rect_points );

    float  angle = rotatedRect.angle; // angle

    // read center of rotated rect
    cv::Point2f center = rotatedRect.center; // center

    // draw rotated rect
    for(unsigned int j=0; j<4; ++j)
        cv::line(input, rect_points[j], rect_points[(j+1)%4], cv::Scalar(0,255,0));

    // draw center and print text
    std::stringstream ss;   ss << angle; // convert float to string
    cv::circle(input, center, 5, cv::Scalar(0,255,0)); // draw center
    cv::putText(input, ss.str(), center + cv::Point2f(-25,25), 
    cv::FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL,1, cv::Scalar(255,0,255)); // print angle
}
```

my code:

```
contours_yellow, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask_yellow, cv2.RETR_TREE, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

yellow_contours = cv2.drawContours(mask_yellow, contours_yellow, -1, (0,255,0), 3)

angle = 0

for contour in yellow_contours :
{
    #fit bounding rectangle around contour
    RotatedRect = minAreaRect(contours_yellow[value])

    #read point and angle
    point2f rect_points[4]
    rotatedRect.points(rect_points)

    angle = rotatedRect.angle; # angle


}

    print (angle)
```

Comment: Did you even try executing your Python code?

Comment: yes of course,  but i got an error with find contours:

OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats ([Start]FindContours supports only CV_8UC1 images when mode != CV_RETR_FLOODFILL otherwise supports CV_32SC1 images only) in cvStartFindContours_Impl, file /build/opencv-L2vuMj/open

Comment: Check the dimensions of the input image, `cv2.findContours` expects an image with single channel as input

Comment: This solved my findcontours problem: contours_yellow, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask_yellow, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]

Comment: The next problem is "RotatedRect = minAreaRect" it won't recognize this function

Comment: please take the [tour] and review [ask] and [mre]. your post contains code that is syntactically invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The function `cv2.minAreaRect()` returns a tuple of 3 elements: the first two are the coordinates of the rotated rectangle and the angle of rotation. We need to print this last element for each contour.

In Python, to obtain the last element in a `list`, `array` or `tuple` you can do `myList[-1]`.

```
img = cv2.imread('white_boxes.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold the image
th = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# find contours 
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(th, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for c in contours:
  rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
  print('Angle:', rect[-1])
```